# Umbraco Server Error: Contact Administrator see log for full details. Logs telling 404 error

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, access-denied, umbraco6, umbraco-blog

I am going to use my Umbraco after a long time but I am unable to edit or post new thing. After Publish Changes it Displays the following error but the website is working perfectly in localhost.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: The image is very small, could you reupload?

Comment: Can you check out the web request in your browser dev tools? The response object is often quite useful in seeing what the actual issue was.

Comment: @Harvey I did it. Sorry for that

Comment: Thanks. What's your user type? It could be "Admninistrator", "Writer" or "Editor".

Comment: user type is Administrator

Comment: Have you read the log to see what the error is? Could you post the log message here?

Comment: 404 GET /umbraco/RestServices/ScheduledPublish/Index - HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 0):

That error looks like a permissions issue maybe? Are the permissions set correctly on the folders for the site?